# Can a MapServer client set the DATARANGE via QueryString

Tags: mapserver

I have a raster layer with data values between 1.7 and 34.6 (data is a GeoTIFF with one band of float32).  I have a simple style(below) to render the data in grayscale.  By adjusting the DATARANGE, I can filter the data to the range of interest.  Is there a way for the caller to specify the DATARANGE on the query string?

```
CLASS
  STYLE
    COLORRANGE 0 0 0 255 255 255
    DATARANGE 25 30
  END
END
```

I’ve tried adding “&map.layer[0].class[0].style[0]=DATARANGE+20+30” to the query string, but I get the error:

loadStyle(): Unknown identifier. Parsing error near (DATARANGE):(line 1)

Answer (score 1):

Warning: I haven't tried this myself.

Expanding on the "Basic Example" in the Runtime Substitution section of http://mapserver.org/cgi/runsub.html#runsub, I suggest this modification.

```
VALIDATION
    'default_lowlimit' '25'
    'default_highlimit' '35'
    'lowlimit' '[0-9]+'
    'highlimit' '[0-9]+'
END
CLASS
  STYLE
    COLORRANGE 0 0 0 255 255 255
    DATARANGE '%lowlimit' '%highlimit'
  END
END
```

The `default_` lines in the VALIDATION block will assign default values. Then the non-`default_` lines give regular expressions to match the incoming values. The query string contains `&lowlimit=25&highlimit=30`.

I'm not thrilled about testing numeric values with a regex. And this sample allows highlimit to be less than lowlimit. Hopefully this gets you started.